# "No doubt Ferguson wants his team to make a fight of it"

Tags: idioms, pronouns

> No doubt Ferguson wants his team to make a fight of it.

In 'make a fight of it', what is 'it'?

Is this just an idiomatic expression? Or the 'it' has some meaning?

Comment: Hi gomadeng, I answered your question, but please [cite the source](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1084/so-you-found-a-sentence-or-phrase-why-you-should-cite-your-source) of your example sentence.

Comment: "It" means whatever the event or situation is, which you didn't include in the quote. If the context is a football match, then "it" means the football match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This use of "make" is more commonly seen in collocations such as "make a mess of (something)" and "make a success of (something)". M-W defines "make" [this way](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/make):

> 16a: to produce as a result of action, effort, or behavior with respect to something
> | *make* a mess of the job
> | tried to *make* a thorough job of it

It is unclear what "it" refers to in your example sentence because you did not include more context. Presumably there is some situation that Ferguson wants to result in a fight. If the team is a sports team, then "fight" probably refers to a competition and not a violent brawl, but without more context I can't be entirely sure.